# How do I change the location of CruiseControl log files?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

The server where CruiseControl.NET is already installed is running out of disk space.

Is there a simple way of moving the CruiseControl logs to another drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it here..  http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Xml+Log+Publisher

The Xml Log Publisher is used to create the log files used by the CruiseControl.NET Web Dashboard, so if you don't define an  section the Dashboard will not function correctly.
    You should place the  in the  section, after any File Merge Tasks, in your Project Configuration Block.
Examples

Minimalist example:

```
<xmllogger />
```

Full example:

```
<xmllogger logDir="c:\myproject\buildlogs" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of moving logs somewhere else, you should also use [Artifact Cleanup Publisher](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Artifact+Cleanup+Publisher) to delete older logs. It is done on a per-project base, usually set up to keep X last build logs or logs from X last days. Also, storing project's [workingDirectory and artifactDirectory](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Project+Configuration+Block) on a separate, large drive is usually a good idea.